# Excel case insensitive sum product

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to do a sum product to compare a cell to a column in another sheet and bring the value in another column associated to the match.

Using :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Item_mst!$H$1:$H$4,--(A1=Item_mst!$B$1:$B$4))
```

sheet 1

```
  Item
   A 
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
```

Item_mst

```
  Item  Qty
   B     H 
1 aaa   20 
2 AAA   10
3 AAA   20
4 AAA   20
```

The above formula gives me aaa/AAA = 60 while the correct value answer I expect is 70. Its not picking up the item when the qty is different and the case doesnt match.

Comment: why not use SUMIF()?

Comment: I tried this =SUMIF(Item_mst!B6:B5966,A80,Item_mst!H6:H5966). But doesnt work

Comment: `=SUMIF(Item_mst!B:B,A1,Item_mst!H:H)` works for me, with the date you provided.  if it does not work check the data to ensure there are not extra spaces or other non-printable character that would make Excel not see as equal

Comment: A1=.75X5.50X144XBKXR063XNA , Is doing sum of everything except 
.75x5.50x144xBKxR063xNA

Comment: again double check that there is no spaces or other non printable character either before or after.  SUMIF is case insensitive.  try it with your data set above.  It does not care if it is `AAA` or `aaa`.

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIFS` would be a better solution

But, to answer the actual Q, try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Item_mst!$D$1:$D$4,--(LOWER(H1)=LOWER(Item_mst!$B$1:$B$4)))
```